# Cannot Pass Values Between 2 popup forms in Access 2013

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a **ListBox** in access 2013 , I need to pass values from (**form1**) to (**form2**) after double click on Lisbox in (**form1**). I have already try this way:
The below code when (**form2**) is activated , it worked normally but if forms 
property popup = true

It not working , values cannot read in (**form2**)    .

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
    If CurrentProject.AllForms("SearchFrm").IsLoaded = True Then
        BBAIDHidenTxt.Value = Forms![SearchFrm]![SearchList].Column(0)
        PrNumberHidenTxt.Value = Forms![SearchFrm]![SearchList].Column(1)
        SupplierHidenTxt.Value = Forms![SearchFrm]![SearchList].Column(2)
        OrderDateHidenTxt.Value = Forms![SearchFrm]![SearchList].Column(3)
        TransactionTypeHidenTxt.Value = Forms![SearchFrm]![SearchList].Column(4)
        TotalValueHidenTxt.Value = Forms![SearchFrm]![SearchList].Column(5)
     End If
End Sub
```

note : i'm new in access database developing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use TempVars or Pubic Variable defined in module to store the value and later access them in other form.
2. Best option is to use OpenArgs option as already mentioned by Minty.

**Form1**

```
Private Sub listBox_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim lstStr As String
    lstStr = Me.listBox.Column(1)
    DoCmd.OpenForm "SearchFrm", acNormal, , , , acDialog, lstStr 
End Sub
```

**Form2**

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        MsgBox Me.OpenArgs
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback , but actually it workig when forms popup property = false but when set it true Form2 not read the passed value i assume that because it already opened so didn't call Form_Load()  Event , all i need tiger in form 2 to get values from OpenArgs

Comment: Before opening the second form add the following code `Docmd.Close acForm, Me.Name` to close the form.

Comment: but i dont need to close it

Comment: @MohamedAbdelrahman I tested the code by setting both popup=true and popup=false and it works

Answer (score 1):

A dialog Popup form stops all code on the calling form until the 2nd form opened is closed.

Pass the value(s) in an Openargs property to the Popup.

Comment: thanks Minty , But i need the 2 forms opened at same time there

Comment: Then move your code to the form you are calling. As I said you can't move focus off the popup form, so you have to make it work from there.